# Exclude all email records from a domain except those that begin with a string

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to exclude all records in a table from a specific domain except for those that begin with a specific string.

So, for example I have a bunch of records with `yopmail.com` as the domain.  I want to exclude all records from `yopmail.com` except those that start with abc.

The current code to exclude is just `WHERE emailAddress NOT LIKE '%yopmail.com'`, but now I need to figure out how to add to that except `'WHERE emailAddress LIKE abc%yopmail.com'`.

I've wracked my brain for how to do this and I can't come up with anything useful.

Ben

Comment: Try `WHERE emailAddress NOT LIKE '%yopmail.com' AND emailAddress NOT LIKE 'abc%'` ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add another condition on your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE emailAddress NOT LIKE '%yopmail.com' OR emailAddress LIKE 'abc%yopmail.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving this mystery is to use [regular expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html). You can match literal characters [A-Z] and use wildcards like # and $ to match strings. The regular expressions can become quite complex, so there are editors available such RegEx Buddy.